# Weblogic osgi bundle

Tags: osgi, weblogic, weblogic12c, osgi-bundle, blueprint-osgi

I have an osgi bundle which was deployed in apache karaf using the feature.xml and service injection is done using blueprint.xml. How to deploy the same bundle in Weblogic OSGI container.

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLPRG/osgi.htm#WLPRG764

I followed the steps mentioned in the above link. Copied the OSGI jar in the WL_HOME/server/osgi-lib location and restarted the server, but was not able to start it. Am i missing some thing?

Note:- I was able to deploy a simple OSGI jar without any dependencies by copying the jar in the osgi-lib folder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Aries blueprint bundles.

Comment: what about the dependency jars.for example in karaf we will be doing a feature:install it will install the dependency jars in karaf first then deploy the osgi bundle. What about weblogic how will i handle the dependency jars. Should i bundle the jars as part of osgi bundle itself?

Comment: How to install aries blueprint bundles in weblogic?